# In one query INSERT and DUPLICATE both done their job

Tags: php, mysql

In my code i have this query:

```
$this->mysqli->query(
    INSERT INTO `address` SET 
    `name` = '$street', `created_at` = '$timestamp' 
    ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE 
    `updated_at` = '$timestamp'");
```

But when program get same name name value he insert new row, and update old in same time.
I done `ADD INDEX(name);` But still I get duplicate values, that I don't want.

I tried with preparing statement and binding param, but same thing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to add a unique key for name.  Instead of doing:

```
create index idx_address_name on address(name);
```

You need:

```
create unique index idx_address_name on address(name);
```

You can declare a unique constraint in other ways as well, such as using the `unique` keyword in a `create table` or `alter table` statement.

With this, your code should work as you expect it to.

Answer (score 0):

You can set unique index for field(s) in the table and send query like this:

```
REPLACE INTO tablename (a,b,c,d) VALUES (?,?,?,?);
```

Comment: Problem is that I need created_at and updated_at, so when I replace row, created_at is lost.